# 'bibtex' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: bibtex

I am using VS Code to compile a document. The problem seems to be the bib file more specifically the error log states

```
'bibtex' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

However, when I upload this on Overlead, it works flawlessly. Why is this happening?

Update: I also get the following

```
LaTeX fatal error: spawn bibtex ENOENT, . PID: undefined.
```

Update: Solution posted below. However, my question still holds; why did biblatex work and natbib didn't? Also, why wasn't bibtex detected before since it was installed this whole time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution. It was inspired by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-in-a-nutshell-for-beginners?noredirect=1&lq=1). I added

```
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,
style=apa,
citestyle=authoryear
]{biblatex}
```

into the .cls file and

```
%\bibliography{bib file without .bib} % deprecated
\addbibresource{bib file with .bib}
```

after `\documentclass`with `\printbibliography` towards the end of the document.